# Ruby on rails -- Render partial file inside .js.erb file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, render

In the HTML header this small javascript works:

application.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               alert("<%= escape_javascript(render('resources/positions')) %>");
</script>
```

But When I tried to put the same code in a js.erb file, it doesn't work.

I tried to inlcude the file, but not working both ways:

```
<script src="/assets/resources.js.erb" type="text/javascript"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'resources' %>
```

app/assets/javascripts/resources.js.erb

```
alert("<%= escape_javascript(render('resources/positions')) %>");
```

any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd check in the generated html that the file you're getting (/assets/resources.js) exists and contains what you expect

Comment: Yes I checked the generated html

Comment: So what's the content of /assets/resources.js? Also check the JS console to see if there's any error message

Comment: there is no errors, and the content is empty... :(

Comment: You might have a problem with the asset pipeline then ... what's your configuration for it ?

Comment: my configutation is config.assets.enabled = true

Comment: Is that supposed to be `render(:partial => 'resources/positions')` I didn't know if there was a slacker way of doing it like that, at least not [documented](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with the asset pipeline.

Try adding

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

In development.rb

Comment: restarted the server and still the same.. I have to use javascript_include_tag ?

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag 'resources' %> and here is my file app/assets/javascripts/resources.js.erb

Comment: Yes use javascript_include_tag

Comment: Even a simple alert(1); doesn't work.. You're sure it's the good path  app/assets/javascripts/resources.js.erb ?

Comment: I don't know, it's your app! How does the generated html script tag look?

Comment: Because I don't know what <%= javascript_include_tag 'resources' %> will generate.

Comment: will generate <script src="/assets/resources.js.erb" type="text/javascript"></script> ??

Comment: Just refresh the page. Then take a look at the <head> in your generated HTML (firebug, chrome inspect, CTRL+U ...)